# Graph API Calls Fail Only for Notifications

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Using this Graph API call:

> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fnotifications

When I make this request (`https://graph.facebook.com/me/notifications`), I get only an empty string returned.  When I request anything else, I get proper responses.  There are no issues with access tokens or permissions.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

1. Are you sure you have the `manage_notifications` permission?
2. Do you definitely have no unread notifications? There'll only be values there in the case where your user has new notifications (i.e the third jewel on www.facebook.com is red and has a number)
3. If you're trying to check for recent (but read) notifications make sure you're including `include_read=1` as a parameter to the call to `/{user id}/notifications`